# Actionscript 3 'this' question

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, this, anonymous-function

I'm aware that's it very common to use `this` as much as possible when writing `ActionScript 3` code *(http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/01/07/we-should-always-use-actionscripts-this-keyword/).*

But what should be done if you're writing anonymous functions, which don't have appropriate `this` matching.

```
x.addEventListener(Event.WHATEVER, function(event:*) {
    // When this callback fires, there is a fail:
    // because there is no 'this' at this point.

    // INVALID!
    this.someAction();
});
```

I saw some recommendations on writing something like:

```
var self = this;
```

and then using `self` in the code of your anonymous functions, but this seems weird.

**What's your opinion on this question *(for example, do you have something about it in your coding standard)*?**

Comment: I would not say it is common to use 'this' all the time in ActionScript. Personally, it is bad practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar approach (so this isn't an answer as much as it is affirmation of your approach):

```
public class myClass extends EventDispatcher{

   public function foo() : void {
      var thisObject : myClass = this;
      this.addEventListener(EVENT, function(event : Event) : void {
         thisObject.foo_internal();
      }, false, 0, true);
   }

   protected function foo_interal() : void {

   }

}
```

Of course, the purist might say that you shouldn't be adding listeners in a manner that prevents you from removing them! That said, we use this convention in other places where we use inner functions outside the context of a listener.

Comment: Purist or not, not removing listeners is generally bad practice, as you're not concerned with the users resources.

Comment: This convention aligns well with Crockford's convention for making a containing object accessible to 'private' methods: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using anonymous function, there is no this (per se).

By defining `self` you are defining a local scope variable that can be then called by reference... personally, I don't like the practice.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific reason for using anonymous functions over named functions?  To quote Grant Skinner:

> in almost every case, the use of an
>   anonymous function in your code
>   indicates an architectural problem.
>   There are almost no real uses for
>   anonymous functions – they are less
>   efficient, much harder to debug, and
>   far harder to grok when reading code.

Here is an interesting discussion about functions and scope from Mike Chamber's blog:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/10/08/function-closures-and-this-in-actionscript-3/

If you scroll down near the bottom of the comments you can find Grant's response.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me to hear that Grant no longer feels this way, given his recent work with JavaScript.  JS uses anonymous functions very effectively, and a lot of those functional concepts work well in AS3 too. This probably isn't the place for that discussion, though...

Answer (score 0):

Edited:  Ah - my bad, I misunderstood.  I typically don't refer to `this` unless it's a self-contained action, etc.  Using `self` or something similar provides a means for other methods to access it.  I personally approach development from this standard, for removing listeners, etc..

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thank you, I obviously understand how `this` statements work and why the scope changes if you're using anonymous functions. I was basically asking if you have some recommendations about something like this in your coding standard / whatever. *Because there are obviously two ways of solving it - forgetting about `this` in anonymous functions or using `self` approach I've described.*

Comment: And I was just gathering opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use methods so "this" will be fixed to the instance, or stop using "this" so Flash Player will search the scope chain.  I prefer letting Flash Player search the scope chain because I think code with "this" everywhere is hard to read.